# Where does <style id="shopify-dynamic-checkout"> come from and how can I override it?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am styling a Shopify site for the first and using the Minimalist theme as a base. I want to style the `shopify-payment-button` (But it now) button but have not been able to. I noticed looking that the page source code there is:

```
<style id="shopify-dynamic-checkout">

.shopify-payment-button__button--hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.shopify-payment-button__button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

//etc, etc
```

being injected into the `<head>` which is overriding my styles. I can't find where this comes from to remove it. Would anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

**Shopify** injects styles and js for some elements on site inside {{ content_for_header }}, which you will find in theme.liquid file.

This tag contains default shopify files as well as files for some integrations and apps. For example if you install facebook pixel through shopify, the code for it will go to {{ content_for_header }}

It is not possible to control what goes to this tag directly. If you just need to change styling then I recommend to just overwrite styles, in worst case if you need to, use`"!important"` tag in css